# How to download a file through an API which provides streams on client side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In my app, I need to download a large zip file and my server(NodeJs) is providing zip using streams to the client but when the file created is too large I am getting network failed error after downloading some amount of file. Here is my sample client code:

```
<form method="post" action="somewhere" >
<input type="text" name="resources[]" value="resource1"/>
<input type="text" name="resources[]" value="resource2"/>
<input type="text" name="resources[]" value="resource3"/>
  <input type="submit" value="post request"/>
</form>
```

Also I after some research I found that it might be possible that the client is unable to consume the streams properly. There I get to know about [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).
Should I try it or there is something wrong on my client or server?
Here is my server sample: [DownloadServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464596/unexpected-behavior-using-zip-stream-npm-on-google-k8s)

Comment: Do your failed requests take the same time always?

Comment: There is no React code in your code snippet, so I can't really help you there.

Comment: in above html code nothing is wrong , add more relevant code to see problem

Comment: @BurakGavas No, neither the time is fixed nor the size is fixed after which it starts getting a network error. I have edited the question please have a look again.

Comment: @mzedeler OK then think of it as plain HTML-JS. I edited the question, please have a look again.

Comment: @AdeelNawaz I edited the question, please have a look again.