# Understanding streams in Node js

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, zipstream, archiverjs

I am stuck on an issue where I need to create and download a zip of multiple files using NodeJs.
Things I have tried and failed :

https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/364#issuecomment-573508251

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90483#issue-606722433

[unexpected behavior using zip-stream NPM on Google k8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464596/unexpected-behavior-using-zip-stream-npm-on-google-k8s)

In addition to this, now the files are encrypted as well so I have to decrypt them before adding them to zip on the fly.

Though I solved this also, my solution works perfectly while the server is running on a local machine but failed when on the Google Kubernetes Engine.

After some more research, I guess this might be because of a backpressure issue in the streams in NodeJs but as described in docs, backpressure is handled by the pipe method automatically.
Is it possible that the receiving speed of the browser is not matching with the sending speed of my server/zipping if yes how to solve this problem?

All the samples related to the problem are in the links provided above.

In Addition to this readable stream is passed through decipher to decrypt it.

```
    const handleEntries = ({ elem, uniqueFiles, archive, speedLimit }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fileName = elem.fileName;
    const url = elem.url;
    const decipher = elem.decipher;
    // changing fileName if same filename is already added to zip
    if (uniqueFiles[fileName] || uniqueFiles[fileName] === 0) {
      uniqueFiles[fileName]++;
    } else {
      uniqueFiles[fileName] = 0;
    }
    if (uniqueFiles[fileName]) {
      const lastDotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
      const name = fileName.substring(0, lastDotIndex);
      const extension = fileName.substring(lastDotIndex + 1);
      fileName = `${name}(${uniqueFiles[fileName]}).${extension}`;
    }
    let readableStream = Request(url);
    // create a "Throttle" instance that reads at speedLimit bps
    if (speedLimit) {
      const throttle = new Throttle({ bps: Number(speedLimit) });
      readableStream = readableStream.pipe(throttle);
    }
    // if file is encrypted, need to decrypt it before piping to zip
    readableStream = decipher ? readableStream.pipe(decipher) : readableStream;
    archive.append(readableStream, { name: fileName });
    readableStream.on("complete", result => {
      console.log("Request stream event complete : ", fileName);
      resolve("done");
      // readableStream.unpipe();
      // readableStream.destroy();
    });
    readableStream
      .on("error", error => {
        console.log("Request stream event error fileName : ", fileName, " error : ", error);
        // readableStream.unpipe();
        // readableStream.destroy();
        resolve("done");
      })
      .on("pipe", result => {
        console.log("Request stream event pipe : ", fileName);
      })
      .on("request", result => {
        console.log("Request stream event request : ", fileName);
      })
      .on("response", result => {
        console.log("Request stream event response : ", fileName);
      })
      .on("socket", result => {
        result.setKeepAlive(true);
        console.log("Request stream event socket : ", fileName);
      });
  });
};

const useArchiver = async ({ resp, urls, speedLimit }) => {
  resp.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/zip",
    "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename="${outputFileName}"`,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
  });
  const uniqueFiles = {};
  const archive = Archiver("zip", { zlib: 0 });
  archive.pipe(resp);
  archive
    .on("close", result => {
      console.log("archive stream event close : ", result);
      // archive.unpipe();
      // archive.destroy();
    })
    .on("drain", result => {
      console.log("archive stream event drain : ", result);
    })
    .on("entry", result => {
      console.log("archive stream event entry : ", result.stats);
    })
    .on("error", error => {
      console.log("archive stream event error : ", error);
      reject("error");
      // archive.unpipe();
      // archive.destroy();
    })
    .on("finish", result => {
      console.log("archive stream event finish : ", result);
      // archive.unpipe();
      // archive.destroy();
    })
    .on("pipe", result => {
      console.log("archive stream event pipe : ");
    })
    .on("progress", async result => {
      console.log("archive stream event progress : ", result.entries);
      if (urls.length === result.entries.total && urls.length === result.entries.processed) {
        await archive.finalize();
        console.log("finalized : ", urls[0]);
      }
    })
    .on("unpipe", result => {
      console.log("archive stream event unpipe : ");
    })
    .on("warning", result => {
      console.log("archive stream event warning : ", result);
    });
  for (const elem of urls) {
    await handleEntries({ elem, uniqueFiles, archive, speedLimit });
  }
};
```

I tried this code with archiver, getting drain event of archiver while zipping large files, does pipe handles back pressure or not if yes why I am getting drain event from archiver.

Comment: Is the problem again present only for large files?

Comment: Yes, still the same issue, I tried many modules like yazl, archiver, zip-stream, zipstream but all behaving same, working fine on local but having issue on google k8s, most probably backpressuring issue. Though pipe handles backpressure itself but doesn't know why there is this problem persists.

Comment: In this case I'm failing to see any significant differences between this question and the one you posted earlier this year, i.e. you knowingly posted a duplicate. You also know the answer to the question already - the operation simply takes too long and your ingress cuts the connection off. Of course it's not a problem in your local environment, since you don't have that setup. Wanna be sure? Send an XHR request from your browser to your local server with a timeout configured and see what happens. Finally, backpressure is indeed handled by Node if you use piping and proper transform streams.

Comment: @Avius I tried this also, changing/configuring timeout on local does not make any change, also timeout is just for initializing response, once the browser starts receiving data timeout does not really matter. Regarding the previous question, later I found out that it wasn't a timeout issue i.e downloading was sometimes working sometimes not even after an increased timeout on ingress. Also, ingress was not disconnecting my connection exactly after the fixed time(timeout) it was all random, neither the file size was same nor the time.

Comment: When you ran it locally, was it directly running on the host, or inside a docker image?

Comment: @Elgarni I ran it Directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I got the solution for this, I did a few changes in Kubernetes configurations i.e increase timeout from 30 secs to 300 secs, increase CPU limit, and tested it multiple times for up to 12-13 GB file and it works like a charm.
**I think increasing CPU from .5 to 1 and increasing timeout did the job for me**.

Answer (score 0):

Hey) I've researched your code and can say you, you use a promise function and you're not waiting until she finish. you need to wrap zipStreamer.entry with await new Promise(). And must be like this

```
async function doSmth() {
   const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
      algorithm,
      Buffer.from(key), 
      Buffer.from(key.substring(0, 9)
   ));
   await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     zipStreamer.entry(readableStream.pipe(decipher), {
      name: fileName
     }, (error, result) => {
      if (!error) {
         resolve("done");
      } else {
        reject("error");
      }
     });  
   });
}
```

Comment: I already did that @Pavel, have a look at my updated question, also refer to this https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/470 for more info regarding the issue.

Comment: Hi @Pavel, thanks for your contribution but this answer is wrong. The problem at hand has nothing to do with promises.

Comment: @Avius Can you share me logs of your app on google kubernetes cloud? They can show us what is wrong there